# Scrapy Spider How to avoid endless cycle between current and next page

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape multiple pages but my crawler ends up cycling between page 1 and 2. How can write a script that moves only moves forward? I tried the following selector, but couldn't move from page 1 to 2.

```
NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = '//span[@class="page-link"]//span[contains(text(),"»")]/preceding-sibling::a/@href'
nextPageUrl = response.urljoin(response.xpath(NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first())
```

In page 1

```
<span class="page-link"><a href=".../page/2/"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span><span class="sr-only">Next page</span></a></span>
```

In page 2

```
<span class="page-link"><a href=".../page/1/"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span><span class="sr-only">Previous page</span></a></span>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show HTML fragment with current page and next page at the same time?

Comment: Scrapy skips duplicate requests by default, so it should not be a problem. Have you disabled duplicate request filtering? (e.g. are you passing `dont_filter=True` to your requests?)

Comment: I did pass don't_filter = True. Without it, the crawler doesn't reach the next page, page 2. But the next page has a link back to page 1, as you can see above.

Comment: Sorry, figured out what the issue was. I set the allowed domain to be 'www.domain.org/' removing 'www' and '/' seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to debug what happened when you use NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR. There is another more easy way to go over all page you need. You can use "parse" method of CrawlSpider. Inside of "parse" method you can get data from the page and then take next page URL to make a yield with callback equal self.parse. It will open next page URL and run "parse" method again with next page URL response.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider


class SomeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'SAME NAME'
    allowed_domains = ['ALLOWED DOMAINS HERE']
    start_urls = ['START_URL'

    def parse(self, response):
        # First you get all data from current page.
        urls = response.css('div.title a::attr(href)').extract()

        for url in urls:
            yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_data_page)

        # Second you get next page URL and yield it with callback.
        next_page = response.css('span.page-link a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_data_page(self, response):
        # Pars
```

Comment: It's an older post from 2019, yes. But in your code, you used a closing  "}". I think it's misplaced there. The correct line of code should be `yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)`